# Images now only share via text messages

Tags: java, android, image, sharing

I'm working on an app to share images. The images are within a gridview and basically when clicking on an image it opens the share menu (a bit like bitmoji). It was working just fine but I added more gridviews to my code, more images, played with the design and never checked if sharing still worked. I just now came to the realisation that the app now shares via text messages only. Instead of opening a list of apps, now it opens my txt messaging app and asks me to choose a contact. I don't know why it's behaving this way.

```
        permissionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            //On click function
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getContext().getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                //Create the intent to start another activity

            }
        });
```

Could it be that the app remembers a choice I made before and has now set it as default?

edit : I modidfied the code but the app behaves the same wa.y. It does not show me a choice of apps.

```
        permissionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            //On click function
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getContext().getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);

                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an app");

                //startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(chooser);

                //Create the intent to start another activity

            }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Did that answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The android framework will remember your last choice if you told it to. You can remove that default choice by going into app settings and clicking clear defaults. You can also use an app chooser:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser